# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I import a project in my Android Studio and get me bellow error :

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/mindmine.com.welcometol
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

And Bellow is my `build.gradle`, I change `minSdkVersion 21` to  `minSdkVersion 8` but get me error yet:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mindmine.com.welcometol"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: On which Android version is the device (emulator) running?

Comment: I don't use (emulator) I connect mobile.My Android Studio Version is : 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you change `minSdkVersion` 21 to  `minSdkVersion` 8 in Manifest

Change it in your Gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mindmine.com.welcometol"
        minSdkVersion *<Put yoru min SDK here>*
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Comment: When I change minSdkVersion 21 to  minSdkVersion 8 it get me error for getDrawable in my code . It tell me call require API level 21.

Comment: change it to getResouces().getDrawable

Comment: @JIM try with `getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx)`, without the second `Theme` parameter.